# How to delay Excel cell error validation until it loses focus?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Excel does this annoying thing where it likes to validate cells for errors with the formulas before I am done typing them.  For instance, if I am writing

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A3, "?*")
```

I would typically write

```
=COUNTIF()
```

in any other language, and then proceed to fill in the arguments inside the parentheses afterward.  However, if I do this in Excel, it causes an error popup message that I then have to exit out of before returning to what I was doing.  Is there any way to change the settings so that this error message won't actually show up unless I leave the cell without completing the formula?

Comment: Type an apostrophe (`'`) in front of the formula, then remove it when you are done with it?

Comment: That would work, or I could also remove the equals sign until I am done, or I could write the formula in a separate text editor and copy it over, but I am specifically looking for a hidden convenience setting somewhere which would delay validation until the cell loses focus.

Answer (score 0):

You can don't enter the "=" with the formula in cell.